# Cannot cancel ical event (dreaded "not supported calendar message.ics")

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I'm writing a system in Python that is using the icalendar library to generate ical invites.  Those work fantastically, but if I try to send out a cancellation Outlook just displays the dreaded "not supported calendar message.ics".  I originally had this issue with the invite, but solved it by fixing my date formatting.

Here is the initial invite:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//myapp//myapp.example.com//
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Weekly Review Meeting
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20200331T190000Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20200331T200000Z
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20200325T193007Z
UID:1@myapp
SEQUENCE:0
ATTENDEE:me@example.com
CATEGORY:EVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:bla bla
LOCATION:Webex
ORGANIZER:donotreply@example.com
PRIORITY:5
STATUS:CONFIRMED
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And then the cancellation:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//myapp//myapp.example.com//
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Weekly Review Meeting
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20200331T190000Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20200331T200000Z
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20200325T193011Z
UID:1@myapp
SEQUENCE:1
ATTENDEE:me@example.com
CATEGORY:EVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:Webex
ORGANIZER:donotreply@example.com
PRIORITY:5
STATUS:CANCELLED
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The same code generates both and sets the `METHOD` and `STATUS` differently (`DESCRIPTION` also differs).  I send a `SEQUENCE` of 0 for the invite and 1 for the cancellation.  The UIDs are always consistent between the matching pair.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up solving this myself.  I will share my learnings for posterity.

The MIME type in the email needs to be set with `method=CANCEL` as well.  This was ultimately my issue. `method` in the MIME type needs to match `METHOD` in the ical file and both are required for Outlook to process it correctly.

`SEQUENCE` should not be incremented for cancellation, just for update.

I also updated all addresses (`ORGANIZER` and `ATTENDEE`) to include `mailto:`, but this does not appear to be strictly necessary.

Comment: The specification explicitly says the sequence must be incremented

Comment: Also, it says that STATUS MUST NOT be included if uninviting specific Attendees (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5546#section-3.2.5)

Comment: Setting the method=CANCEL worked for me. SEQUENCE can be incremented as mentioned in the docs.